# Returning a Task of type Task<Dictionary<string, string>>

Tags: c#, dictionary, task, async-await

I've been trying to figure out how to return data in type Task other than an int like this for example, `Task<Dictionary<string, string>>`.

All the examples I seem to find all show returning an `Task<int>`. which is easy enough to do by saying `return 42;`.

The function I've been trying to write works something like this:

```
Task<Dictionary<string, string>> getDamaged()
{
    Task<Dictionary<string, string>> d = new Task<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    Dictionary<string, string> e = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (Building i in buildingArray)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(i.efficiency) < 100)
        {
            e.Add(i.buildingID, i.buildingName);
            //d.Add(i.buildingID, i.buildingName);  // this does not work, either
        }
    }
```

I found the [Task.FromResult method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922.aspx) which looked somewhat promising, but further investigation appears to show that `TResult` as a completed task which to me sounds not necessarily like one that you can `await`.

Any ideas on how to get this working correctly?

*Update*

The point of this method is I am trying to offload work from my UI thread to keep my UI responsive.  This is one of my first attempts at really trying to do this using visual studio 2012 with .net4.5.  The code above I wrote from memory.  I'll post the actual code I've been attempting along with commented out failed attempts.

One part that really bugs me is that if I return a int if my return type is task, but if I try with dictionary I get an error about cannot implicitly convert a dictionary  to a task

```
    private Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetDamagedBuildings()
    {
        //Task<Dictionary<string, string>> damagedBuildings = new Task<Dictionary<string,string>>();
        Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (ButtonPlanetMap i in buttonArray)
        {
            //Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            if (Convert.ToInt32(i.efficiency) < 100)
            {
                d.Add(i.buildingID.ToString(), i.buildingName);
                //(Dictionary<string, string>)damagedBuildings.
            }
        }
        //damagedBuildings = Cast d;
        //return damagedBuildings;
        return d;
    }
```

Comment: Mark the function as `async`.

Comment: Why exactly does it need to be a `Task`? Your method is completely synchronous, so why bother? Can't you just return a `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: Kirill Shlenskiy I'm intending this method to be one that I can await from inside another method.  As far as my understanding of async and await work to use the keyword async you have to have an await somewhere in the function.  And await only works when calling yet another method that returns a task.  If I'm incorrect in this understanding please do correct me.

Comment: @Jazzeroki: Your question was rather confusing; Lee and I each answered from different assumptions. Svick has the best answer, covering both of our answers and more very clearly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing special about `int`, you can return a `Dictionary` from your method exactly the same way.

What exactly you should do depends on why does your method return a `Task`.

1. If you don't have good reason for returning a `Task`, don't return a `Task`, return the `Dictionary` directly.
2. If you're returning a `Task` to fulfill an interface, but you don't actually want to make your method asynchronous, `Task.FromResult()` is a good solution. You can use it something like this: `return Task.FromResult(dictionary);`. Such `Task` can still be `await`ed, it's just that the `await` will complete immediately.
3. If you're returning a `Task` because your method is CPU intensive and you want to execute it on a background thread, then you should use `Task.Run()`:

   ```
   return Task.Run(() =>
   {
       var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       …
       return dictionary;
   });
   ```

   But doing this is often not a good idea, see [*Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

Comment: I intended to make this method possible to use async because it is meant to be called by a ui, and I'm trying to unload as much work as possible from my ui thread to keep it responsive.

Comment: I haven't tried doing it exaclty as you you did with the lambda expression and anonymous method.  Not a bad idea I may use that in some other areas of the project I'm working on.  What really bugs me is that visual studion 2012 will let me use return and an int if my return type is task<int> but it gives me an implicit conversion error if I attempt to return just a dictionary.  That's why I'm trying to figure out how to convert a dictionary<string,string> to Task<dictionary<string,string>>

Comment: @Jazzeroki Is your `int` method marked as `async`? That could explain the difference. Also, MS's guidelines for WinRT are that method that takes more than 50 ms should make asynchronous. Does your method take more than 50 ms? If not, then it's probably not worth making it `async`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Task.FromResult` will mean your method runs synchronously and then return a completed task, which is probably not what you intend (although you can await a completed task).

You can start a new task using [TaskFactory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321455.aspx). If you are using .Net 4.5, you can use [Task.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194918.aspx) instead which uses `TaskFactory.StartNew` with some common default arguments.

```
Task<Dictionary<string,string>> GetDamaged()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        Dictionary <string, string> e = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach(Building i in buildingArray)
        {
            if(Convert.ToInt32(i.efficiency) < 100)
            {
                e.Add(i.buildingID, i.buildingName);
            }
        }

        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Task.Run` > `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: May I humbly suggest two improvements to the presentation of your answer? **1.** It shouldn't contain anything that _"also does not work"_. Being a solution, all of it should work. :) **2.** It might have been better to focus solely on the `Task.Factory.StartNew(…)` part instead of copy-and-pasting the question's code over (see also my first point); now, has to compare the question's code with your answer's code to see what the exact differences are that make it work. (Granted, it's not difficult to figure it out.)

Answer (score 1):

When your `async` method has a return value of `Task<int>`, then your code should return an `int`. Similarly, when your `async` method has a return value of `Task<Dictionary<string, string>>`, then your code should return a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

```
async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> getDamagedAsync()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> e = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var buildingArray = await GetBuildingsAsync();
    foreach (Building i in buildingArray)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(i.efficiency) < 100)
        {
            e.Add(i.buildingID, i.buildingName);
        }
    }

    return e;
}
```

Comment: This assumes the method is `async`, I don't see any indication of that in the question.

Comment: Yes. I assumed it would be `async` since the op mentioned they understood how `Task<int>` methods return `int` values.

Comment: svick you are right that I left the async keyword off.  That was deliberate because my understanding of async was that without an await the method still just runs synchronously.  Stephen Clearly I actually tried the method you suggested on my first attempt at figuring this out and Visual Studio 2012 is giving me an error saying that I can't implicetly convert a dictionary to a task<dictionary>.

Comment: @Jazzeroki: The `async` keyword is what translates `T` to `Task<T>`.

Comment: Stephen Clearly Thanks that was the answer I needed.  Thank you everyone else for all the other feedback and tips.